# Adding a library a Haskell Project

Tags: haskell

I am going through some of the Haskell exercises in [exercism](http://exercism.io/). I have reached a point where I need to include a library in my project. But to be more clear I would like to include the library Data.List.Split. The library can be found [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.2/docs/Data-List-Split.html)

I have tried going through some of [Stack's](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) documentation and I don't seem to understand how to do it. My project has:

1. `package.yaml`
2. `stack.yaml`
3. `cabal` file

I wish they had a "dummies guide to using stack", something absolute beginners would be able understand.

Please use examples as you explain your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found another way to do it. I needed to insert `split` as one of the dependencies in the `package.yaml` file like this:

```yaml
dependencies:
    - split
```

This is the followed up by deleting the `cabal` file and then typing `stack build` in the terminal.

The result is that it creates a new `cabal` file without me having to make any specific changes to the `cabal` file.

The new `cabal` file now has `split` as one the dependencies as so:

```yaml
build-depends:
    base
  , split
```

At the top of the newly generated `cabal` file it says that it has been generated from the `package.yaml` file by `hpack`.

Answer (score 1):

You should add your library `split` and the specific version to the `cabal` file in the `build-depends` section. So for example, if you have in your `cabal` file the following:

```
build-depends:
  base >=4.7
```

now `Stack` knows that your project depends on the `base` library and it should require a version greater or equal to `4.7`. Hence, to add your `split` library, you should add something like:

```
build-depends:
  split == 0.2.3.2
```

That says simply that you need the `0.2.3.2` version of the `split` library.

Here you can read more about this: [Stack documentation](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) (read the workflow section) and here you have an example of a `cabal` file that requires some libraries [project.cabal example](https://github.com/nicodelpiano/coverage/blob/master/coverage.cabal#L48).

Comment: Thanks. How did you know to use the word `split` and not Data.List.Split

Comment: That's because the name of the library is `split`: go to https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.2 and you will see the legend `split: Combinator library for splitting lists`. Also, from the url you have `split-0.2.3.2`, which is parsed as `{name-of-the-library}-{version-of-the-library}`. `Data.List.Split` is the library's module structure and just says how you will import it. Here you have the actual `cabal` file for the `split` lib: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.2/split.cabal